# Maven project pom sourceDirectory as method parameter

Tags: java, rest, api, maven, pom.xml

I am working on an auto generation class which generates jsonObjects from schemas given. The idea is to have a folder containing all schemas and then be able to go through all the schemas and process as needed. My question is how do I pass in the sourceDirectory defined in the pom as a parameter. And how do I access outputDirectory also. 
for example, I have a class like this

```
public void generateJSONOrder() throws JSONException, IOException
{
    File folder = <sourceDirecotry>; // how do I get this ?
    // other code here and then write output
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(<outputDirectory>)); //how to get this too?

}
```

Comment: You should be able to find you answer : https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html se how application-home is set and retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) and then use any of below options
to access the values in your code

1. Set System Properties
2. Write to Properties File

Somthing like this.

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>schemaSourceDirectory</name>
                        <value>\pathToSchema</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Simply use maven tool [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) to Generates Java types from JSON Schema, with this tool you can specify `sourceDirectory` and also `targetPackage`

Comment: I already have that. I am trying to define my own but pass in <sourceDirectory> as a parameter

Comment: Than you could use properties-maven-plugin